# Can I make an early application for a UK tourist visa to circumvent the 3-month application time rule?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am planning to apply for a UK Standard Visitor Visa for an activity that will take place 6 months from now.  I am aware that the maximum lead time for a UK visa is 3 months and that applications asking for a longer lead time will be refused.

So can I apply now and then wait for my event to occur and then travel?

Comment: It doesn't pay to lie on a visa application. If the immigration officer suspects you're not being completely honest you're likely to have your application refused. If he thinks you're being deliberately deceitful you could be banned for up to 10 years.

Comment: What do you mean "since application is going to be banned"?

Comment: Do I understand this right? You want to travel to the UK in 6 months time, so you will apply for a visa saying you will travel in 3 months (and stay several months), but not do that, and instead travel in 6 months time and stay for two weeks?

Comment: DJClayworth, that's almost right. And I don't want to trick anybody, since plans can really change over the time. And finally my visa duration period will be reduced significantly.

Comment: By application is going to be banned I mean refusal

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. This is a seriously bad idea. If you submit an application without an itinerary you'll probably be refused because your plans aren't clear. If you submit an itinerary you'll need to submit supporting documentation like flight tickets, hotel bookings etc. Assume the immigration service will check these. If you apply early and submit an accurate itinerary you'll be refused and told to apply later. If you submit a false itinerary there are many opportunities for Immigration to spot the inconsistencies. More...

Comment: ...If you are caught lying you **will** be refused and you **will** be banned. Why do this at all? Why not just wait until the right time and submit a proper application?

Comment: @StanislavBoykov "And I don't want to trick anybody, since plans can really change over the time." You seem to have a serious problem with lying. What you actually mean is that you _do_ want to trick the British government by telling them that you intend to travel on one date and then pretending that your plans changed when, in reality, you planned to travel at the later date all along.

Comment: Well, looks like this is not a good idea... In this case it's really better to wait 3 months more and visit visa center later. The problem is that the nearest one is 3,000 km far away from me, thanks for the endless Russian territory. Anyway thank you guys for advises, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to this question has been posted by user Gayot Fow [on his blog](https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/2017/11/21/uk-tourist-visa-early-application/):

> Your strategy assumes that the visa’s start date is when you arrive in the UK, and hence it is misconceived.  The visa’s start date is stated explicitly on its face as an immutable point in time.  So the answer to your question is no.
>
> However, people apply for their visas for all kinds of reasons and have all kinds of different circumstances and it is not abnormal for some people to travel after their visa’s start date.  There is no requirement that a person travel on the visa’s start date, or the day after the start date, or any time near the start date.  Who originates these crazy ideas anyway?
>
> So if you want to travel some time between the visa’s start and end dates, that’s fine. As long as you observe the 3 month maximum lead time, there’s no problem.

[CC BY-SA 3.0](https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/about/). Unchanged.

Comment: Maybe these "crazy" ideas originate with Russian visas where, on my reading (yet to get one) your first entrance must be exactly that indicated on the visa application.